# Why I can not find spyder-notebook plugin in Anacodna navigator?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, ide, spyder

I am trying to install the spyder-notebook plugin:
https://docs.spyder-ide.org/5/plugins/notebook.html
but for some reason when I search for it in Anaconda I can not find it.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EnZR.png)

In the documentation, it also mentioned that installing the plugin is no longer from a standalone installer, but I guess anaconda is not a stand-alone installer, right?

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBftj.png)

Appreciate your help,
Thanks

Comment: This plugin is currently only supported for Spyder 4 (although some work in being done [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-notebook/pull/369) to make it work with Spyder 5) and from `conda` you need to use the `spyder-ide` channel to get it as mentioned in the [plugin repository README](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-notebook#installation) and the [instructions in the Spyder documentation](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/5/plugins/notebook.html#installing-the-notebook). If you want to use Anaconda Navigator you need to be sure to have `spyder-ide` as a possible channel

Comment: @DanielAlthviz
Thank you